# javascript : send actual html code to url

Tags: javascript, html, encode

I have an array of HTML codes like this :

```
array = ['&#37;', '&#85']
```

that I would like to send to URL as :

```
url + '&#37;,&#85;'
```

but when I write :

```
url + array
```

the result is :

```
url%,U
```

Is there a way or function to send the HTML code as it is ?

Comment: Where do you have that code? Why is this getting **de**coded? Are you placing it in HTML?

Comment: What are the reasons behind this requirement? Maybe there is another way to go about this

Comment: When I write url + array in browser console, I get what you expect. I think you need to clarify WHAT and WHY. Why don't you use encodeURIComponent()? Do you have to use elements of that array? If so, how/where you get your result like in question? On backend? If so, how do you send it to backend; via AJAX or from form? Do you use pure JS or some library/framework? Give us complete test case so we don't spend time guessing ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could probably just put your stringified array into the [encodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) function, which takes care of all non-URL-save special chars and then use the reverse function [decodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent) (or its equivalent in other languages) to get the original data back as a string.
So what you probably should do is

```
encoded = encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(array))
decoded = JSON.parse(decodeURIComponent(array))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
myArray = ['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc'];
var arrStr = encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify(myArray));
$('#myLink').attr({ href: '/myLink?array=' + arrStr });
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert `array` to a string first before appending it to the `url`.

```js
var array = ['&#37;', '&#85'];
var url = 'foo.baz';

console.log(url + array.join(','));
```

Comment: The problem isn't with joining the array - implicit conversion to string is already `.join(",")`. The problem is that the encoded characters somehow get decoded.

Answer (score -2):

This would help you.

```js
let array = ['&#37;', '&#85'];
let url = 'https://jsfiddle.net/';
console.log(url+array)
```

Comment: How is this different to what OP does?